# Unfortunately, app has stopped while logging

Tags: android, android-sqlite, runtimeexception, sqliteopenhelper, android-runtime

I'm trying to make an android app for logging but when I run it it tells me app has stopped and here is my login activity:

```
public class Connexion extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText PWDEDIT;
    EditText LOGINEDIT;
    String loginedit;
    String pwdedit;
    Context CTX = this;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "login ou mot de passe incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connexion);
        b = (Button) findViewById(connexion);
        PWDEDIT = (EditText) findViewById(passwordeditText);
        LOGINEDIT = (EditText) findViewById(logineditText);




        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                loginedit = LOGINEDIT.getText().toString();
                pwdedit = PWDEDIT.getText().toString();
                DataBaseOperationstwo DOP = new DataBaseOperationstwo(CTX);
                Cursor CR = DOP.getloginuser(DOP);
                CR.moveToFirst();
                boolean loginstatus = false;
                String NAME = "";
                do {
                    if (loginedit.equals(CR.getString(0)) && (pwdedit.equals(CR.getString(1)))) {
                        loginstatus = true;
                        NAME = CR.getString(0);
                    }
                } while (CR.moveToNext());
                if (loginstatus) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "authentification réussie \n Bienvenue" + NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    finish();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    finish();


                }


            }
        });


    }
}
```

and here is my sqliteopenhelper class:

```
 public class DataBaseOperationstwo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public static final  int database_version = 10;
 public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME +" ("+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT );";
 //clé etranger avec utilisateur
   //                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + TASK_CAT + " integer,"   + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TASK_CAT+") REFERENCES "+CAT_TABLE+" ("+CAT_ID+"));";
//foreign key doone !!
 private static final String CREATE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NOTE_NAME +" (" +
 TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTE+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.TITRE+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.OBJET+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.PRAM_N+" VARCHAR (255)," + TableData.TableInfo.EIDUSER+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.EIDUSER+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_USER+"));";
//foreign key done!!
 private static final String CREATE_ARCHIVE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_ARCHIVE_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_ARCHIVE+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.ARCHIVE_NOTEID+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.ARCHIVE_NOTEID+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NOTE_NAME+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTE+"));";
 //cv no FK
 private static final String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER +" (" +
 TableData.TableInfo.UID_USER+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.NOM+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.PRENOM+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.DATE_NAISS+" DATE,"+ TableData.TableInfo.E_MAIL+
 " VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.LOGIN+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.MOT_PASSE+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.GENRE+" VARCHAR (255) );";
 //cv FK dooooone!!
 private static final String CREATE_INSCRIPTION = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_INSCRIPTION_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_USERI+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.NOMI+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.PRENOMI+"VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.DATE_NAISSI+
 "DATE,"+ TableData.TableInfo.E_MAILI+"VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.LOGINI+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.MOT_PASSEI+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.INC_IDUSER+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.INC_IDUSER+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_USER+"));";
//FK DOONE
    private static final String CREATE_AUTHENTIFICATION = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_AUTHENTIFICATION_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.LOGINA+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.MOT_PASSEA+" VARCHAR (255),"+ TableData.TableInfo.AIDUSER+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.AIDUSER+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_USER+"));";
    //cv no FK
 private static final String CREATE_MESSAGE= "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_MESSAGE_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_MESSAGE+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TableData.TableInfo.TEXTE_MESSAGE +" VARCHAR(255) );";
    //cv no FK
 private static final String CREATE_MESSAGE_FORUM = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_MESSAGE_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_MESSAGE+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.SUJET_MESSAGE +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TEXTE_MESSAGE+" VARCHAR(255) );";
    //FK CV
 private static final String CREATE_FORUM = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_FORUM_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_FORUM+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTEF+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTEF+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NOTE_NAME+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTE+"));";
 // clé etran\\CV
 private static final String CREATE_NOTIFICATION = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NOTIFICATION_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_USERN+
 " INTEGER, " + TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTEN + TableData.TableInfo.UID_MESSAGE+
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.TEXTE_MESSAGE +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.OBJET_NOTIFICATION+ " VARCHAR(255) )"+TableData.TableInfo.NIDUSER+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.NIDUSER+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_USER+"));";
//insertion mrigel!!
 private static final String CREATE_INSERTION = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_INSERTION_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255)"+ TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTEINSERT+ " integer," + " FOREIGN KEY ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTEINSERT+") REFERENCES "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NOTE_NAME+" ("+TableData.TableInfo.UID_NOTE+"));";

 private static final String CREATE_ATEMPORAIRE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_ATEMPORAIRE_NAME+" (" + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.DATE_ATEMPORAIRE+
 " VARCHAR(255) );";

 private static final String CREATE_AGEOGRAPHIQUE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_AGEOGRAPHIQUE+" ("  + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.LOCALISATION_AGEOGRAPHIQUE+
 " VARCHAR(255) );";

 private static final String CREATE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_IMAGE_NAME+" ("  + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255) );" ;

 private static final String CREATE_AUDIO = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_AUDIO_NAME+" ("  + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255) );" ;

 private static final String CREATE_VIDEO = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_VIDEO_NAME+" ("  + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255) );" ;

 private static final String CREATE_DOCUMENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_DOCUMENT_NAME+" ("  + TableData.TableInfo.UID_INSERTION+
 " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.PATH_INSERTION +" VARCHAR(255)," + TableData.TableInfo.TAILLE_INSERTION+ " VARCHAR(255) );" ;


 public DataBaseOperationstwo(Context context){
 super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME,null,database_version);
 Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS", "DATABASE CREATED");


 }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

            Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS","note CREATED");
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_ARCHIVE);

            db.execSQL(CREATE_INSCRIPTION);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_AUTHENTIFICATION);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGE_FORUM);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_FORUM);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTIFICATION);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_INSERTION);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_ATEMPORAIRE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_AGEOGRAPHIQUE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_AUDIO);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_VIDEO);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DOCUMENT);
            onCreate(db);
            Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS","new tables CREATED");
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS","error"+e);
        }

    }
    public void putuser(DataBaseOperationstwo dop,String nom,String prenom,String datenaiss,String mail,String login,String pwd,String genre)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.NOM, nom);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.PRENOM, prenom);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.DATE_NAISS, datenaiss);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.E_MAIL, mail);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.LOGIN, login);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.MOT_PASSE, pwd);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.GENRE, genre);

        long k = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER,null,cv);
        Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS","One row inserted ");


    }
    public Cursor getloginuser(DataBaseOperationstwo dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloums = {TableData.TableInfo.LOGIN, TableData.TableInfo.MOT_PASSE};
        Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER,coloums,null,null,null,null,null);
        return CR;


    }
    public void putnote(DataBaseOperationstwo dop,String titre,String objet)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.TITRE, titre);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.OBJET, objet);


        long k = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_USER,null,cv);
        Log.d("SANADATABASE OPERATIONS","One row inserted ");


    }
    }
```

And last but not least my logcat when i try to open my app:

```
04-30 13:41:43.796    1388-1388/com.example.hp.memorybackup D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-30 13:41:43.816    1388-1388/com.example.hp.memorybackup W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-30 13:41:44.156    1388-1388/com.example.hp.memorybackup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.memorybackup/com.example.hp.memorybackup.Connexion}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
            at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
            at com.example.hp.memorybackup.Connexion.<init>(Connexion.java:34)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 13:42:07.967    1388-1388/com.example.hp.memorybackup I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1388 SIG: 9
```

However it it declared in my Android manifest.

Comment: you can't declare and initialise a class member that needs a Context object, at the same time

Comment: what is at line number Connexion.java:34 ?

Comment: @Blackbelt i'm sorry i didnt' unterstand can u explain more?

Comment: @yushi that is my main activity called connexion it is already posted

Comment: @SanaZorgui WHAT IS LINE NUMBER 34 IN Connexion.java

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are getting Resource id wrong add R.id use the following this will help you.

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connexion);
PWDEDIT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordeditText);
LOGINEDIT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logineditText);
```

when you are getting the text from textview it is null because of findingViewById wrongly.

Comment: hi i did what you said but the problem is still there

Comment: now the exception is same or different from the last exception? if different please post that log this might help to find out the issue

Comment: i'm afraid it is the axact same exeption well it is something related to the logging code the rest used to work perfectly when i tried to add the login code it crashes i hope this could help the problem is definetlyy there